# TypeConverter not working for android Room DB

Tags: kotlin, android-room

So I am trying to save a list of string pairs into my database but having some issues with the TypeConverter, I tried following guides ans other SO posts but can't figure out whats wrong...

My Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Credential(
    @PrimaryKey()
    val id: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    val url: String?,

    @TypeConverters(ListPairTypeConverter::class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fields")
    val fields: List<Pair<String, String>>
)
```

My Type Converter:

```
class ListPairTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun storedStringToPairList(value: String): List<Pair<String, String>> {
        return value.split("~!!!!!~").map {
            val vals = it.split("!~~~~~!")
            Pair(vals[0], vals[1])
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun pairListToStoredString(pl: List<Pair<String, String>>): String {
        return pl.joinToString(separator = "~!!!!!~") { it.first + "!~~~~~!" + it.second }
    }
}
```

My Error:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<kotlin.Pair<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>> fields = null;
                                                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding type converter at wrong place. instead of

```
@TypeConverters(ListPairTypeConverter::class)
@ColumnInfo(name = "fields")
val fields: List<Pair<String, String>>
```

You need to add at here

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(ListPairTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
  abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! First time trying to use Room DB